# jQuery: How to enable save btn after file been uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, button

What is the best way to accomplish this. Trying to figure out how can you enabled the submit Btn after file has been uploaded. Is it possible? Hope I explain myself clearly. Thank you in advance.

[image]

**HTML code**

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div id="divPharmacy">
                <label asp-for="Pharmacy">Pharmacy Location</label>
                <select asp-for="Pharmacy" class="form-control"
                    id="Pharmacy" required>
                    <option value="" selected>-- Please choose an option --</option>
                    <option value="CVS">CVS</option>
                    <option value="Publix">Publix</option>
                    <option value="Walgreens">Walgreens</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <input type="file"  id="upload-file" name="myfile" /><br />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
            <button id="btnSubmit" value="Validate!" id="upload" type="submit"
                class="btn btn-success text-center"
            asp-action="FinalView" disabled>Save</button>
    </div>
```

**jQuery code** Enable upload button after the file been uploaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input:submit").attr("disabled", true);
  $("input:file").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $("input:submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      $("input:submit").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });  
});
```

Comment: you can use ajax to it and once it click disable the button then in success enable it

Answer (score 0):

In ajax call once you upload your file then it returns with success here you can enable it @jerson is also mentioned in a comment same thing.